# What is the default value <html lang="???">

Tags: html, lang

If I don't specify a value in the `lang` attribute of the `html` tag, what default value does it take? Is it 'en'?

Comment: You really could've google'd this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html

The default value of this attribute is unknown.

Comment: Or the more up-to-date (and much more complex) definition: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#attr-lang

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Read the section on [inheritance](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.1.2) which states that the default value can come from a number of sources (similar to the HTML5 spec quoted in my answer).

Comment: In fact, the 4.01 spec doesn't actually state the value is unknown, like the HTML5 spec does. It goes as far as saying it will use "User agent default values and user preferences".

Answer (score 5):

The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#attr-lang) goes into a bit more detail than HTML4.01:

> If neither the node nor any of the node's ancestors, including the root element, have either attribute set, but there is a pragma-set default language set, then that is the language of the node. If there is no pragma-set default language set, then language information from a higher-level protocol (such as HTTP), if any, must be used as the final fallback language instead. In the absence of any such language information, and in cases where the higher-level protocol reports multiple languages, the language of the node is unknown, and the corresponding language tag is the empty string.

So to summarise that, the `lang` of a node is determined by:

- The `xml:lang` attribute value of the node or an ancestor (in this case we're talking about the root node so there are no ancestors)
- The `lang` attribute value of the node or an ancestor
- The [pragma-set default language](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/document-metadata.html#pragma-set-default-language)
- HTTP headers (or details from some other protocol if not HTTP)
- If none of the above, then the value is unknown

Comment: Note though that in `text/html` on the `html` element, `xml:lang` is not a `lang` attribute in the XML namespace, but a `xml:lang` attribute in no namespace, so its setting would not apply.